# Decouple client (browser) from Vue frontend and Python backend running on Kubernetes containers

Tags: vue.js, kubernetes, webpack, decoupling

I have a Vue frontend application that runs on a Kubernetes container. This application communicates with a backend server running on a different Kubernetes container. The frontend Vue application uses Webpack and injects the full application into the client (browser) storage. Due to this, the browser (client) is the one that is doing the fetch calls to the backend. I can see this on the developer console, network tab. Due to security reasons, we want the browser (client) to interact only with the Kubernetes Vue frontend and be the internal frontend application the one that does the calls to the backend. Is there any way to achieve this with Vue, or is there any framework that works with Vue that allows us to do this easily?

Thanks

I expect that the client does only calls to the internal Vue frontend and that no backend calls are done by the browser

Comment: Which security reasons exactly? "client does only calls to the internal Vue frontend and that no backend calls" - it's unclear how it's supposed to work exactly. Can you clarify with an example that explains the requests?

Comment: @EstusFlask The backend uses a URL that is not externalised. Only the frontend url is external. The idea is for the browser to only interact with the frontend URL, and do backend calls from the frontend Kubernetes pod, not from the browser

Comment: What is the reasoning for this? Is available data supposed to be the same in BE and FE? Basically, if you don't want to expose backend url in order to have some control over it like rate limiting in FE container, you can proxy api calls, e.g. with WP https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy . If you need to not expose some api calls at all to make data parsing harder, you need to go SSR partially or fully, e.g. nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components#server-components . These seem to be the options

Comment: Fundamentally your application needs to accept an HTTP request from the public Internet that reaches the backend service.  How would you prove that the request comes from your frontend application (running in the end user's browser) as opposed to some other path?